# Default text in Inputbox function

Tags: vba, outlook

Is it possible to add some text into the `inputBox` text field without having to create a `userForm`. Does a named argument exist to do this ?

[image]

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Yes, The 3rd argument is for the Default text in InputBox.

Comment: ^ See the [`InputBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/inputbox-function) documentation for more detail.

Comment: wow. how did i miss this, i was just looking at the documentation and somehow missed something so obvious. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**See like this:**

[Link to Information on InputBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/inputbox-function)

[image]